# What is the correct query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the correct query for this requirement?

Assume there is an object which has to go under a checking procedure every few month to be validated.
The outgoing information of this procedure is stored in postgres. When the object is checked again, it is validated again.
An object may be revalidated within its own (near ending) validation date interval.

Requirement: **Select all records which have not been revalidated.**

My work so fare: Select all objects which are not valid. But i cannot (with my knowledge) exclude the objects which have been revalidated.

The outcome of this dbfiddle query is an record which has been revalidated an should therefore not show.
Thank you for help.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocHQNXQJKUPKYGN35LBeFK/3

Important columns are here:

1. device_serial_no: identifacation of the object
2. validated: the date on which the object has been validated
3. validated_for_month: the interval in month which has to pass, respective the validated column date, for becoming not valid. So its valid for
   `validated + concat(valitated_for_month, ' month')::interval`

Query 1: Data set

Query 2: Wrong results, object has been revalidated.

**Expected: No object shows up.**

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.5)**

```
CREATE TABLE public.einrichtungen (
    id serial,
    messplatz varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    gegenstand varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    validated timestamp NOT NULL,
    valitated_for_month int8 NOT NULL,
    active bool NOT NULL,
    device_serial_no varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

insert into einrichtungen(messplatz, gegenstand, validated, valitated_for_month, active, device_serial_no) values ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-04-08 10:37:59', 24, true, 'SDHFEJ');

insert into einrichtungen(messplatz, gegenstand, validated, valitated_for_month, active, device_serial_no) values ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-03-01 10:37:59', 12, true, 'XX1');

insert into einrichtungen(messplatz, gegenstand, validated, valitated_for_month, active, device_serial_no) values ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2021-02-15 11:12:19', 12, true, 'XX1');

insert into einrichtungen(messplatz, gegenstand, validated, valitated_for_month, active, device_serial_no) values ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-04-08 10:37:59', 24, true, 'JSDFIE');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from einrichtungen;
```

| id | messplatz | gegenstand | validated | valitated_for_month | active | device_serial_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HV1 | Messuhr | 2020-04-08T10:37:59.000Z | 24 | true | SDHFEJ |
| 2 | HV1 | Messuhr | 2020-03-01T10:37:59.000Z | 12 | true | XX1 |
| 3 | HV1 | Messuhr | 2021-02-15T11:12:19.000Z | 12 | true | XX1 |
| 4 | HV1 | Messuhr | 2020-04-08T10:37:59.000Z | 24 | true | JSDFIE |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from einrichtungen where validated + concat(valitated_for_month, ' month')::interval < now();
```

| id | messplatz | gegenstand | validated | valitated_for_month | active | device_serial_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | HV1 | Messuhr | 2020-03-01T10:37:59.000Z | 12 | true | XX1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocHQNXQJKUPKYGN35LBeFK/3)

Comment: The fiddle is great, but you should also add sample data and the expected result here, because a SO question is supposed to be self-contained. (SO is a great Q&A archive, but the fiddle link will soon be gone.)

Comment: Also: `(NOT) EXISTS (subquery on the same table)` is what you want.

Comment: @wildplasser ive looked up the EXISTS operator, but i have issues applying it to this case. can you explain further? many thanks

Comment: **1)** What is the purpose of device_serial_number? **2)** Validated_for month:  is this the *length* of an interval? (in that case al your measurements will overlap)

Comment: 1.) object identification
2.) yes, length of an interval in months

Comment: ...and while we're at it, "what is the correct query" is a *horrible* question title. It's right up there with "please help me" and "something is wrong". Nobody will ever benefit from that. You think you could come up with a better title, one that actually describes what your question is about?

Comment: The results that you want would be really helpful.  If the non-English language columns are not needed, you can also remove them from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect, because I don't completely understand the question, but it will get you started. I also omitted the irrelevant columns.

---

```
CREATE TABLE einrichtungen (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    , messplatz varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , gegenstand varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , validated timestamp NOT NULL
    , validated_for_month int8 NOT NULL
    , active bool NOT NULL
    , device_serial_no varchar(255) NOT NULL
        );

insert into einrichtungen(messplatz, gegenstand, validated, validated_for_month, active, device_serial_no) values
('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-04-08 10:37:59', 24, true, 'SDHFEJ')
, ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2010-03-01 10:37:59', 12, true, 'XX1') -- extra
, ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-03-01 10:37:59', 12, true, 'XX1')
, ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2021-02-15 11:12:19', 12, true, 'XX1')
, ('HV1', 'Messuhr', '2020-04-08 10:37:59', 24, true, 'JSDFIE')
        ;

SELECT *
FROM einrichtungen e
WHERE 1=1
AND e.validated + e.validated_for_month * '1 mon'::interval < now()
AND e.active
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM einrichtungen nx
        WHERE nx.device_serial_no = e.device_serial_no
        AND nx.validated > e.validated
        AND nx.validated <= e.validated + e.validated_for_month * '1 mon'::interval
        );
```